# Ubuntu and Static IP Address

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, dhcp, ifconfig

I'm trying to figure out how I can assign a static IP address to my default ethernet adapter `eth0` - all attempts so far have been fruitless and ended up in frustration.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on an NVIDIA Jetson TK1 ARM platform.

Ideally, I want the interface `eth0` to assume an IP address such as `192.168.0.xxx` as per our company network scheme.

Using `network-manager`, I've tried (and failed) to manually assign an IP address. However, checking with `ifconfig` reports an altogether different IP which appears to be DHCP assigned (the IP address changes very regularly).

I have tried un-installing network manager and using the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to statically assign an address to `eth0` however following this, I get a lot of `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable` errors and no IP ever appears to be assigned to `eth0`.

Why does `network-manager` not seem to work in this instance? I have a `vino` VNC server running on my Ubuntu TK1 platform and the only IP address which allows me to connect is the DHCP address allocated away from `network-manager`

Confused!

*UPDATE*

After re-visiting this, I'm no closer to figuring out what is going on.

What I have tried since the original message was posted:

1. Disabled `network-manager`
2. Assigned an IP address on a different subnet to our company network so that the DHCP server cannot allocate it an IP address
3. Set up a static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` with the following information

>

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.200.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

When I take the `eth0` interface down and back up again, I see this static IP address assigned correctly. After a while, however, a lot of `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable` messages appear and the IP address *disappears* from `eth0`

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/452317/both-dhcp-and-static-ip-addresses-simultaneously-on-one-interface  and https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager for references

Comment: What you write seems strange indeed. I am running 16.04 where they went away from eth0 naming convention, but I do not know about 14.04. Anyway you might want to consider to add some more data to your question as ifconfig and error message printouts, interface file content or even a screenshot of your network manager configuration page.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `ifconfig` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: And also have you run service networkmanager stop or rebooted?

Comment: I've updated the original question with some further information. I just don't understand why static IP allocation suddenly stops. Its really difficult to capture any terminal output due to the RTNETLINK messages appearing constantly

Answer (score 1):

setting up a static IP address can be done through the GUI in Ubuntu 18.04.

- Click your connection in top right menu bar.
- Click your connection and click `wired/wi-fi settings`
- Click the settings icon on the `Wired/ Visible Networks` section.
- In `addresses` (try in `ipv4` tab if not visible, select `manual`):

  - for `address`, you will need to enter the static IP address of your choice (eg. `192.168.0.3`).
  - set `netmask` to `255.255.255.0`.
  - set `gateway` to the IP address of your network gateway (most likely `192.168.0.1`).
- In DNS section, set this to your target devices *current* IP address (`192.168.0.x`), also can be found for the specific device by navigating to your gateway IP (`192.168.0.1`).
- Next to DNS section, set the `Automatic` switch to off.
- Click `Apply`.
- Disconnect internet (`sudo dhclient -r && sudo dhclient`), connect again and navigate to gateway settings, your device should now have adopted the static IP (`192.168.0.3`) you set.