# Add static IP in Ubuntu 16.04 Host Laptop

Tags: networking, internet, static-ip

I have HP laptop with an external wifi Adapter as there is no Wifi adapter inbuild.

This is my `ifconfig` result

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fc:cf:ad:7c  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:e7:c6:7c:81:c3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6880 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:580042 (580.0 KB)  TX bytes:580042 (580.0 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlx502b73e86298 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:2b:73:e8:62:98  
          inet addr:192.168.43.254  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a85:c587:3653:359/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42520401 (42.5 MB)  TX bytes:6912557 (6.9 MB)
```

I take my IP is `192.168.43.254` and wifi adapter is `wlx502b73e86298`

Now when I connect to another WIFI, my IP changes to

192.168.0.106

**Can I keep some static IP lets say `192.168.0.10` and no matter whichever WIFI I am connected it should work fine?**

I have tried following configuration in

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces



auto wlx502b73e86298
iface wlx502b73e86298 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

And than run these commands

```
sudo ip addr flush wlx502b73e86298

 sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```

Now if I do `ifconfig` I can see my IP as 192.168.0.10

but `ping google.com` doesn't work and I cant access the internet.

Why I need a static IP is because I have a few containers running in Docker and all are pointing to Host IP. If Host IP changes I have to change IP in each container.

Comment: As long as every wifi you connect to has a Gateway of 192.168.0.1 and no one else has the IP address of 192.168.0.10, then yes you could set your IP statically to that, but it is not recommended.

Comment: are you able to ping an IP adress instead of google.com? i guess it is a dns problem. Perhaps NetworkManager is the problem here. Stop and disable networmanager and try again `sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service` . Or you could try to delete the `dns-nameserver` line.

Answer (score 0):

Use your localhost? 127.0.0.1.

You will need to bind your docker containers to localhost using something like "docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:5000 base/theApp python theApp.py".

If this isn't an option you can use, you got two options.

The best solution is to bind your mac-address to your ip in all the dhcp-servers.

If you don't have access to the dhcp-server config you need to use a dhcp (dynamic setup) and an sub-interface with a static ip. Just remember to validate this with your network owner, otherwise it can cause network duplicate address errors. There is already a thread on this here [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452317/both-dhcp-and-static-ip-addresses-simultaneously-on-one-interface)

Just add interface:[interface no] to add another interface configuration.

Example:

> auto lo eth0 eth0:0 iface lo inet loopback
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> iface eth0:0 inet static
>       address ...
>       netmask ...